# Is there a way to search and hide all columns that do not contain a value entered into a given cell?

Tags: excel, vba, search

I need to Hide all rows that do not contain partial value typed into a particular cell but cannot figure out how to define the cell as the search value and not a particular string using VBA in Excel.

I have been able to hide all rows that contain the exact value typed into a cell but need to match all partial values as well.

```
For a = 2 To 200
If Worksheets("Purchase Log").Cells(a, 2).Value = Cells(1, 35) Then    
Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = False 
Else
Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = True
End If
```

If I type in 5555 into cell (1,35) and click the button, all cells that do not contain any of the sequence 5555 are hidden and all rows that have (example)
1555522 remain unhidden.

Comment: instead using `=` use `Like "*" & cells(1, 35) & "*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Like` should do the trick:

```
For a = 2 To 200
    If Worksheets("Purchase Log").Cells(a, 2).Value Like "*" & Cells(1, 35) & "*" Then
        Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = False
    Else
        Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped you, please consider accepting the answer, so others can benefit from it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use InStr() for partial matches:

```
For a = 2 To 200
    If InStr(Worksheets("Purchase Log").Cells(a, 2).Value, Cells(1, 35).Value) Then 
        Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = False
    Else
        Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = True
    End If
Next a
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this non VBA answer as might be easier for some users.

It is possible to Hide Rows/Columns based on the cell value with the integrated find and replace tool.

1. Select which cells you want to search
2. Open "Find and Replace" (CTRL+H)
3. Select the "Find" Tab and enter what you want search and hide.
4. Press"Find All"
5. Select all the result In the Find All Result Table (CTRL-A)
6. Press The Scroll Down On the Right Side to get the control back to the mainwindows without losing the selection
7. Select Row of all resulted Cell (SHIFT-SPACE)
8. Select Column of all resulted Cell (CTRL-SPACE)
9. Right Click on the Selected Row(Header) or Column(Header) that will be highlighted
10. Press Hide

I think this is really helpfull solution as it doesn't require to add VBA, Macro, Function, Filter etc

Have an Awesome Day.
Dan